# Looping JSON Array in JSONB field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-13

I want to loop over `JSONB` column and get certain values (`price`, `discount_price`, and `currency`) of relevant `JSON` objects to my filter. But I get this error:

```
syntax error at or near "FOR"
```

Value of the `parts` column which is `JSONB`:

```
[
    {
        "item_tags": ["black", "optional"],
        "name": "Keyboard",
        "price": 50,
        "currency": "USD",
        "discount_price": 40
    },
    {
        "item_tags": ["white", "optional"],
        "name": "Mouse",
        "price": 40,
        "currency": "USD",
        "discount_price": 30
    }
]
```

My query (`$1` is the user input. Can be 'optional' or 'required'):

```
SELECT
    id,
    title,
    FOR element IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(parts)
        LOOP
            CASE
                WHEN element->'item_tags' @> $1
                    THEN SELECT element->>'discount_price' AS price, element->>'currency' AS currency
                ELSE SELECT element->>'price' AS price, element->>'currency' AS currency
            END
        END LOOP
FROM items;
```

This is the output I want to get if `$1` is equal to 'optional':

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "example title",
    "parts": [
        {
            "name": "Keyboard",
            "discount_price": 40,
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        {
            "name": "Mouse",
            "discount_price": 30,
            "currency": "USD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. I follow official docs but it is not beginner-friendly. I use PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: You can't use a FOR loop inside a SELECT statement. It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve  there. Please [edit] your question and add the expected output based on your sample

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the comment. Edited and added the changes. Please write if anything further is needed

Comment: Your sample data contains two "optional" prices. What is the rule to chose the second over the first?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, my bad. Both of them should be seen in the output. Edited my question

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Now I see that I need to use it in WHERE clause because I'm gonna filter data with this user input

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have any suggestions? I was waiting to get answer but nobody posted yet. I can't overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to unnest the array, filter out the unwanted parts, remove the unwanted key, then aggregate the changed parts back into a JSON array.

This can be done using a scalar sub-query:

```
select id, title, 
       (select jsonb_agg(x.part - 'item_tags') 
        from jsonb_array_elements(i.parts) as x(part)
        where (x.part -> 'item_tags') ? 'optional')
from items i;
```

The expression `x.part - 'item_tags'` removes the `item_tags` key from the JSON object. The `?` operator tests if the `item_tags` array contains the string on the right hand side. And `jsonb_agg()` then aggregates those JSON values back into an array.

You can pass your parameter in the place of the `'optional'` string.